# Falling stones attached by a string

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, string, free-fall, tidal-effect

Suppose we have two stones, one "big" (A) and one "small" (B), the smaller one over the big one at the moment of free fall. Suppose also that a string of a certain length is attached to both stones (this string is initially loose). In the reference frame of the Earth we know that heavier bodies fall with bigger acceleration (that's because the Earth is not an inertial frame of reference and assuming a two body problem in vacuum). **The question:** what happens when the string gets in tension?

Comment: "we know that heavier bodies fall with bigger acceleration" That isn't obvious at all to me... Even when taking into account that Earth frame isn't inertial, the inertial forces are both proportional to mass, so the mass cancels out in Newton's law. Only the drag force could prevent that, but you didn't mention it and it has nothing to do with Earth frame being inertial or not.

Comment: It is true that the *lower* stone (which happens to be the larger one) will fall faster because it's closer to the Earth; this is an example of [tidal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force).  Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Re, "what happens when the string gets in tension?" An _ideal_ string does nothing except constrain the distance by which the two stones can be separated. If you try to pull one stone further away from the other than the length of the string, then the force would be instantly transmitted to the other stone. A _real_ string adds several complications. The biggest being, that it will act like a [_damped spring_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator) when stretched out. Describing how that would affect your stones is beyond my skill level.

Answer (score 0):

You have it mixed up. The heavy stone will have greater acceleration, but not because it is heavy but because it is closer to earth. If you were to arrange them the other way around the lighter stone would then have great acceleration.
If you write the equation of motion for each body separately you can see that the mass of an object in a gravitational field does not affect its acceleration.

$$m_{s}a_s = \frac{GM_{e}m{s}}{r^2}\to a_s = \frac{GM_{e}}{r^2}$$

where the subscript s is for stone and e for earth. Only the magnitude of acceleration is considered and can be seen to depend only on the distance from the earth and not the mass of the free falling object.

The force on the string between the two stones in that case is called a tidal force

Comment: For a considerable difference in acceleration, the distance between the heavier and the lighter stone should be very large which is not true for all practical purposes.

Comment: In the case of the the gravitational field of the Earth you are correct, but when considering heavier objects tidal forces can be significant over small distance separations. Near a black hole for example. The question was imposed as a thought experiment, so I guess all limits must be considered

Comment: The question was posed with Earth as the frame of reference. If we were to consider a black hole, additional complications like Spaghettification would get involved.

Comment: Feels like you didn't finish the last sentence there. Did I answer you or do you still need clarification ?

Comment: The question is meant as a thought experiment. The distance of both stones from the centre of the Earth  at the beginning is to be considered the same: of course, during the free fall, acceleration will vary because of its dependence on distance. The point that need no discussion is the fact that, referred to the Earth's frame reference, acceleration is mass dependent: the effect is very small, being governed by the ratio m/M where M is the mass of the Earth. But that's not a problem! It's a "conceptual matter".

Comment: This question of mine had its origin on Galilei's thought experiment on falling bodies: we now know that he was wrong, nevertheless we have to continue his reasoning just from the point he has discarded as absurd.